# SQL Server Management Studio executable deleted

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

One of my colleague has accidentally deleted SQL Server Management Studio 2016 executable (ssms.exe) from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio.

Can it be restored ?

Comment: If it was backed up it can be restored. An easier solution might just be to download the install and reinstall it, or copy it from another machine.

Comment: If it's in the recycle bin it can definitely be restored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just ran the setup file and choose restore :)